# Does Apache FileUtils have a way to account for BOMs when appending to a UTF-16 file?

Tags: java, utf-16, byte-order-mark, fileutils

I've got a large set of data that includes Spanish and English characters that I'm buffering and streaming to a file. The first push does great and writes a new UTF-16BE \w BOM file.

When I try to append the next set of data though, FileUtils.write() calls String.getBytes("UTF-16") which creates another BOM at the beginning of the byte array that it's about to append.

Is there a way to tell FileUtils to detect if it's appending and trim the BOM if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think i figured out what I want to do.

```
private byte[] withoutBOM(final String string, final Charset encoding) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] bytes = string.getBytes(encoding);
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, bytes.length % string.length(), bytes.length);
}
```

This will assume that any encodings will be an even multiple of the string (UTF-16 for instance has two bytes for every one character) and trims off any metadata from the beginning of the byte array. This way I can just call this method without knowing what the encoding actually is any time I detect that I'm appending to a file

Answer (score 0):

In Java by default the charset "UTF-16" always adds the BOM at the beginning. However the two variants "UTF-16BE" and "UTF-16LE" does not write a BOM:

From the documentation of [Charset](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) (see the "when encoding" parts):

> When decoding, the UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE charsets interpret the initial byte-order marks as a ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE; when encoding, they do not write byte-order marks.
>
> When decoding, the UTF-16 charset interprets the byte-order mark at the beginning of the input stream to indicate the byte-order of the stream but defaults to big-endian if there is no byte-order mark; when encoding, it uses big-endian byte order and writes a big-endian byte-order mark.

Therefore you just have to check an existing BOM and select the appropriate encoding for adding UTF-16 text to your file.

BTW: For English and Spanish texts UTF-8 would be sufficient and much more efficient...

Comment: If I tell java to use UTF-8 i get bad characters for things like "Balcón"

Comment: If you write it as UTF-8 and read it a UTF-8 the character will be correct. Only if you write it as UTF-8 and read it as ANSI you will have defect characters. But that is a problem with your viewer/editor.

Comment: Oh, got it. I wrongly assumed that UTF-8 wasn't handling it because it was only one byte as opposed to the UTF-16's two bytes

Comment: UTF-8 stores non-Ascii characters using two, three, or four bytes (just as needed by the character). The rest is stored using one byte. This is especially efficient for languages that have only certain special characters, rarely used.